# Ajax always returns the length of JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello could someone explain why ajax always returns the length of JSON?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#addElem").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var val1 = $('#addname').val();
       var val2 = $ ('#addprice').val();
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'server.php',
           dataType:"json",
           data: {name: val1, action:'set', price: val2},
           success: function( data ){
                var ident = $('#text').append( data );

           }
       }).done(function(data) {
            alert(data)
       });

   });
});
```

***EDITED:***
here is a server.php
https://jsfiddle.net/nvy2cavz/

***SOLVED
It was not  my mistake .It was a  Server.php  deal . THE SERVER.php always work only in that way.
THANK YOU ALL***

Comment: This question is not very clear... do you mean the the data returned in your $.ajax success callback only contains the length of the JSON string? In which case it would the code in server.php that would need to be examined.

Comment: Post the code of php script that handles the return callback

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser to open developer tools. There should be a "Network" pane (or a similar one) where you can inspect the exact data being sent. I'm almost more that if AJAX receives something it's because that's what's being sent in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is returning the length of `items` array. That's what you are getting in data. It's not the length of JSON but length (number) returned by your server side code.

```
// rest of the code
if($_POST['action'] == 'set') {
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price'])){
        $item = [
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'price' => $_POST['price']
        ];
        $items[] = $item;
        file_put_contents('items.json', json_encode($items));
        $return = json_encode(count($items)-1); //<<<<<<<<<<<<< Change here if you want
    } else {
        $return = json_encode(['error' => 'Wrong item details']);
    }
}
// rest of the code
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.append` function receives (`htmlString or Element or Text or Array or jQuery`).
How can you use `json` object `$.append`? Your `data` object in `success` function is javascript object. I think the problem is hidden here.